# Problems making a proper java sudoku generator

Tags: java, algorithm, while-loop, lwjgl, sudoku

So here's what I got

```
package sud.util;

import java.util.Random;

public class SudoGrid {

    Random gen;

    private int[][] grid;
    private int[] fail;
    private int[]   succes;

    public void init(){
        gen = new Random();
        grid = new int[9][9];
        fail = new int[3];
        succes = new int[3];

        fail[0] = 0;
        fail[1] = 0;
        fail[2] = 0;

        succes[0] = 0;
        succes[1] = 0;
        succes[2] = 0;
    }

    public int[][] generate() {

        for (int x = 0; x < 9; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < 9; y++) {

                boolean isValid = false;


                do{
                    int num = gen.nextInt(9) + 1;


                    if ((checkRow(num, x) != true
                            || checkCol(num, y) != true
                            ||checkSection(num, x, y) != true)){

                        //System.out.println("Row  failed: "+fail[0]+" times, and succeeded:"+succes[0]+" times");
                        //System.out.println("Col  failed: "+fail[1]+" times, and succeeded:"+succes[1]+" times");
                        //System.out.println("Sec failed: "+fail[2]+" times, and succeeded:"+succes[2]+" times\n----------------------------");
                        printBlock();

                    }else if ((checkRow(num, x) == true
                            && checkCol(num, y) == true
                            &&checkSection(num, x, y) == true)){




                        grid[x][y] = num;

                        isValid = true;
                    }

                }while(isValid == false);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("\n######################################################");
        System.out.println("########################CHEESE########################");
        System.out.println("######################################################\n");
        printBlock();
        return grid;
    }

    private boolean checkRow(int num, int row) {//Check a specific row

        boolean valid = true;
        for (int c = 0; c < 9; c++) {
            if (grid[row][c] == num) {
                valid = false;

               break;
            }
        }
        if(valid == false){
            fail[0]++;
        }else{
            succes[0]++;
        }

        return valid;
    }

    private boolean checkCol(int num, int col) {//Checks a specific col

        boolean valid = true;
        for (int r = 0; r < 9; r++) {
            if (grid[r][col] == num) {
                valid = false;

                break;
            }
        }
        if(valid == false){
            fail[1]++;
        }else{
            succes[1]++;
        }
        return valid;
    }

    private boolean checkSection(int num, int xPos, int yPos) {//Checks a 3x3 square

        int[][] section = new int[3][3];
        section = getSection(xPos, yPos);

        boolean valid = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                if (section[i][j] == num) {
                    valid = false;
                  break;
                }
            }
        }
        if(valid == false){
            fail[2]++;
        }else{
            succes[2]++;
        }
        return valid;
    }


    private int[][] getSection(int xPos, int yPos) {

        int xIndex = 0;
        int yIndex = 0;
        int[][] section = new int[3][3];

        if (xPos == 0 || xPos == 3 || xPos == 6) {
            xIndex = xPos;
        } else if (xPos == 1 || xPos == 4 || xPos == 7) {
            xIndex = xPos - 1;
        } else if (xPos == 2 || xPos == 5 || xPos == 8) {
            xIndex = xPos - 2;
        }

        if (yPos == 0 || yPos == 3 || yPos == 6) {
            yIndex = yPos;
        } else if (yPos == 1 || yPos == 4 || yPos == 7) {
            yIndex = yPos - 1;
        } else if (yPos == 2 || yPos == 5 || yPos == 8) {
            yIndex = yPos - 2;
        }

        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;

        for (int x = xIndex; x < 3; x++) {
            for (int y = yIndex; y < 3; y++) {
                section[x][y] = grid[i][j];
                i++;
            }
            j++;
        }

        return section;

    }

    public void printBlock() {
        String str = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++) { 
            for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++) { 
                str += " " + (grid[i][j]);
            }
            str += "\n";
        }
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

This is what `printBlock();` returns after a while

9 5 6 1 3 4 8 7 2
 7 1 3 8 5 2 9 6 4
 6 8 5 7 4 1 3 2 9
 3 7 8 6 9 5 1 4 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

There is something wrong with my section check but I can't seem to find it.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Please provide some example output showing the problem.

Comment: @Dukeling These isin't much to show accept check for yourself.
I checked `printBlock()` To see what was going on but it never passes the first 3 rows, It just starts over again q.q And I've been running it for 2 hours straight now.

Comment: I think you've over complicated this at least a little bit. I would build 9 3x3 grids that, by design, are guaranteed not to conflict. Then build a 2d array of the 2d arrays. This allows you do deal with the arranging a little easier.

Comment: @BobbyDigital That was my first solution, the first of 20. this is my final, But as Dukeling Suggested I do need to implement backtracking. Problem is i still don't have no idea how to yet

Answer (score 2):

When you get into a scenario like this for example:

```
 1 2 3 | 4 5 6 | 7 8 9
 4 5 6 | 1 2 3 |
```

There's no valid value that you can fill in in the next cell.

To deal with this, you need to add [backtracking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking), i.e. if you can't find a valid value for a cell, go back and try different values for previously generated cells.

Hint to do this - consider adding a `bool tryCell(int x, int y)` function which runs your do-while loop, and inside the loop, call `tryCell` for the next cell, and only call `tryCell(0,0)` in `generate`. If this doesn't make sense to you, I suggest you look online for a Sudoku generator with backtracking, there should be plenty.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are getting into an infinite loop in your `do ... while` because in sudokus there are some number configurations when there is no valid number for given field.

You should detect this situations and if that occurs you should go back to a previous field and try to generate another number.